# Where do I download JDBC drivers for DB2 that are compatible with JDK 1.5?

Tags: jdbc, db2

Where do I download JDBC drivers for DB2 that are compatible with JDK 1.5? They seem to be *very* elusive and I hit many dead-ends at IBM's website. I managed to find versions of the driver bundled with some tools such as IBM Data Studio. Unfortunately, these versions either target a JVM too modern (JDK 1.6, leading to class version errors) or too ancient (JDK 1.2, leading to known bugs when run on JDK 1.5).

Comment: IIRC, all available DB2 JDBC drivers should be already in the `/java` or `/jdbc` folder of the DB2 installation folder. Ask your DB admin to have a copy of them if you don't have direct access to the machine where DB2 runs. They're not all downloadable for license reasons. But that may have changed nowadays.

Comment: @BalusC: I managed to gain access to the DB2 server (more specifically: DB2 Express-C). Under its `java` directory, I found `db2jcc.jar` (compiled against JDK 1.2) and `db2jcc4.jar` (compiled against JDK 1.6). :( I will keep looking.

Comment: Oh bummer. I'd call IBM DB2 support line then... Edit: oh wait, the Express-C is the community edition? I checked its site and I think the 2nd driver link here https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=4020&uid=swg21385217 should be helpful (I only don't remember my IBM login anymore so I could download it). JDBC3 should be 1.5 compatible.

Comment: please check mark correct answer ! it's for long time was correct, Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I know its late but i recently ran into this situation. After wasting entire day I finally found the solution. I am suprised that I got this info on [oracle's website](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24902_01/doc.91/e18837/manage_jdbc_drivers.htm#EOISM220) whereas this seems nowhere to be found on IBM's website.

If you want to use JDBC drivers for DB2 that are compatible with JDK 1.5 or 1.4 , you need to use the jar `db2jcc.jar`, which is available in `SQLLIB/java/` folder of your db2 installation.

Comment: Easy check: On a command prompt with Java 1.5 in the path, execute java -cp db2jcc.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version. I found that 3.69.66 is still compatible with 1.5, but 4.19.66, db2jcc4.jar is not.

Comment: Yep, it was in installation of db2. `/opt/IBM/db2/V10.1/java` for mac

Answer (score 4):

official Link of [DB 2 JDBC Driver](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866) from IBM

Answer (score 2):

Right here: http://jt400.sourceforge.net/

This is what I use for that exact purpose.

EDIT: Usage Examples (minus exceptions):

```
// Driver initialization
AS400JDBCDriver driver = new com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver();
DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);

// JDBC Connection URL
String url = "jdbc:as400://10.10.10.10" + ";promt=false" // disable GUI prompting by jt400 library

// Get a Connection object (this is used to create statements, etc)
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, UserString, PassString);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Do you have any examples of how I use that driver to connect? It doesn't seem to have the traditional `com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver` driver.

Answer (score 0):

you can download and install db2client and looking for 
 - db2jcc.jar
 - db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar
 - db2jcc_license_cu.jar
 - and etc.
at C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\java