# where do i download jdbc driver for DB2 8.1?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, db2, spring-jdbc

I'm planing to develop a web application with spring framework. I am using DB2 8.1 as database ,but did not find any JDBC driver for accessing DB2 from java.

Comment: Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678298/where-do-i-download-jdbc-drivers-for-db2-that-are-compatible-with-jdk-1-5

Comment: DB2 JDBC drivers are distributed alongside the DB2 itself (keyword is JCC). AFAIK these drivers are not publicly available. Also note that you will need two JARs - the driver itself and license JAR. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0512kokkat/

Comment: I found jars. I think these jars are compiled with JDK 1.4. But I am using jdk 7.how to resolve this compatibility issue?

Comment: What compatibility issue? Java is backwards compatible, there should be no issue...

Comment: Why do you need that old driver? New drivers can work with old db2 versions. It is not necessary to match server and driver version

Comment: @AngocA please let me know the link/driver location for db2 8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most recent JDBC drivers, you can get them from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

The drivers for 8.1 are not there, but the names are there. You can use any from the 9.1 version to connect to the 8.2 server.